# Using a 32bits windows OS and jdk 1.7, can i succeed writing a cloud based application using java Netbeans

Tags: java

I have tried using my 32bits windows operating system and my jdk1.7 version to design a cloud base application but my netbeans wants me to use a higher jdk version like versions 7 to 8.

I think this caused my java code not to be fully compiled. I couldn't insert data into my table in WAMP server.

When I tried downloading a newer jdk, I discovered my windows OS version could not match those higher versions that were in the website. Is there anything I can do about it, or should i just buy a new PC containing a 64bits windows OS for the job?.

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: Sorry, but your chain of logic here is highly flawed.  First, Java 1.7 is the same as Java 7, they changed the naming convention.  Second, _"i think this caused my java code not to be fully compiled(i could'nt insert data into my table in WAMP server)"_ is a non-sequitur. If your code wasn't fully compiled it couldn't even _begin_ to execute.  Then _"i discovered my windows OS version could not match those higher versions that were in the website"_ also does not make sense unless you are running an ancient Windows such as XP or NT.

Comment: Also, unless your PC is also ancient, the hardware should support 64bit Windows.  What make/model is your PC, how much memory do you have, and what version of Windows are you using?  As it stands right now, nobody can possibly help you until some basic details are provided.

Comment: Thanks, i am using Windows 7 professional,Make - HP, Model -  pavillion dv5,space -140gigabyte

Answer (score 0):

I've installed jdk with netbeans bundle from oracle web site for older versions of windows like XP and for 32 bit PC's, there is no need to buy hole new PC.

jdk 7 and netbeans for windows x86 for 32 bit PC:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html

and jdk 8 netbeans for windows x86 for 32 bit PC:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

I understand that you use WAMP for data base extensions on the web but you're going to need Tomcat or Glassfish for Java based web apps.

Comment: Dropwizard and SparkJava don't require Tomcat or GlassFish to run Java webapps, by the way

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 for the info, I did not know about them.

Comment: Might be worth looking at if you or your employer uses containerized deployments

Comment: thanks @Martin Ruiz to your comment, i have gotten the JDK version 8 with my 32bit windows processor and it is working perfectly now.